# SQL Server - how to use specific subquestion?

Tags: sql-server, database

We have started sql subquestion at school but I can't go throuhg them as easy as with previous topics. I don't even know how to start:

**Table Oddzialy** (means branches):

[image: Table Oddzialy]
                           Oddzial - branch
Adres - Address

**Table Stanowiska** (means positions):

[image]

- Stanowisko - position
- Placa_min - minimum salary
- Placa_max - maximum salary

**Table Pracownicy** (means employees):

[image]

- Nazwisko - surname
- Stanowisko - position
- Szef - chief
- Zatrudniony - employed
- Placa_pod - minimum salary
- Placa_dod - extra salary
- ID_Oddz - ID of Oddzial (branch)

Ok. Question is: display the shortest employed workers (`Pracownicy`) from every branch (`Oddzial`). Results should be ordered in accordance with the order of employment.

Tip: use `INNER JOIN (SELECT…) a ON …`

Comment: Pracownicy? where is this column? :)

Comment: @DamianoBarbati its a table..

Comment: What do you mean by "Shortest"? Shortest period of employment? Also what does "ordered in accordance with order of emplyment" imply?

Comment: @Shiva - yes, I meant the shortest period of employment by "Shortest". Second thing: first record should be person with the longest 
length of service, then someone who will be person with the longest length of service if we exclude the first one. And so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query. It uses `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the shortest employed person for each branch:

```
select * from Pracownicy p
inner join 
    (select ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Oddz ORDER BY Zatrudniony DESC) Ord
    from Pracownicy) x
on p.id = x.id and x.Ord = 1
order by Zatrudniony
```

---

Another way, using "core" SQL functionality, would be:

```
select * 
from Pracownicy p1
where ID =
    (select top 1 ID from Pracownicy p2
     where p1.ID_Oddz = p2.ID_Oddz
     order by Zatrudniony DESC)
order by p1.Zatrudniony
```

Comment: I guess it's a school exercise to test their sql language capabilities, so maybe we should try to avoid any sql engine function / shortcut :)

Comment: I think that there shouldn't be shortcuts but thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe there isn't. I think I will use your example. Thank you.